# VS cannot load VSPerfControl.Interop

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When attempting to use the profiler in Visual Studio Ultimate 2010, the IDE throws the titular error. I've looked around, but the only thing I could find was adding the file to the GAC, but this does not appear to have solved my problem. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download and install the [Visual Studio 2010 Performance Tools with Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23205)

This resolved this error for me, but YMMV